# C - Monitoring files with processes

Tags: c, file, monitoring, process

I have to watch a certain number of log files (which can be changed at any time) to see if they contain a word «forbidden» when this words are in a struct. During the implementation I have some doubt about the best way to do the implementation.

1. Would it be a good idea to have a process to analyse the list of files to be monitored, and each time we see that one had change, we send a process to see if that contains some word “forbidden”?
2. As a log file, the modification only happened in the end, so to see if the file has changed we have to see if the size has been modified too. Doing an «active waiting»:

```
While(1)
 if (“old size!= new size”)
  send process run for this file to see if contains some words “forbidden”.
```

Could someone give me some ideas and tell me if what I'm doing is somehow incorrect?

Comment: Operating systems provide special interfaces for this sort of thing. Would you need solutions for different OSes or can you restrict to a specific OS?

Comment: If you keep track of the previous size, you might as well `seek()` to that position and only read and examine the new contents.

Comment: I completely agree with Dmitri Chubarov, for example for Linux you have inotify. Is this something you can use?

Comment: @fred Any idea why `less` wouldn't use inotify on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

This seems really similar to what `less` does, for a single file.  Using `strace` I peeked a bit at what `less` does, and it seems to just keep an open file descriptor, then in a loop sleep for one second and try to read more input.  If there aren't too many log files to monitor (and you wouldn't mind keeping an open file descriptor to each one), perhaps you could use this approach.